# Safe to leave Ubuntu desktop on for a month?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ssh, hardware, xrdp

I'll be travelling overseas for a month to visit family, and will need to keep up with some GPU sim work only possible on my desktop.

The current plan is to connect with ssh and xrdp (not remote desktop that comes with Ubuntu since that requires the physical monitor to be connected) over a DDNS and it seems to work fine, however I don't have a device that can send WOL packets.

Would leaving the desktop (generic gaming setup 3080Ti and I9) on for a month propose any risks? Any other things I should watch out for? Thanks!

Comment: Hmm... I have laptops that I haven't powered off for _years_. The machine doesn't know you're away, but if the concern is leaving powered-on electrical appliances running while you're away, you may want to ask in another forum as it's more related to electrical safety and fire hazards etc. than to Unix.

Comment: Additionally, you do not need the monitor powered on though. Some people will still believe that you do...

Comment: It's totally fine to do that.  If you're worried about strangers connecting to your machine via ssh, then make sure you disable root logins, perhaps password logins (use an ssh-key instead), and try something `fail2ban` to block IP addresses that are constantly trying to log in.